# PDF/A 1b gets corrupted with digital signature

Tags: java, pdf, itext, digital-signature, pdfa

After inserting digital signature visualisation in a valid PDF/A 1b document, pdf document is not a valid PDF/A document any more. Using Adobe Reader validation following error is found:
[image]

iText 5.5.11 is used. Signature image is in gray scale and without transparency channel. This error only occurrs in one type of documents (in most cases digital signature doesn't corrupt pdfa format).

Unfortunately I cannot provide sample document since it is owned by our customer.

If additional info is needed please let me know.

Any help is much appretiated.

Comment: You say "since it is owned by our customer." Does this mean you are a customer of iText Software? If so, you can share the document under NDA with iText Premium support. If not, please explain under which license you are using iText.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie You'd still have to adhere to the NDA with the customer; I would request explicit written confirmation that you can share it under NDA with iText before doing so.

Comment: What's the signing code you used?